# Beginning to ask a question on Stack Overflow actually helps me debug my problem myself

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, fun

Beginning to ask a question on Stack Overflow actually helps me debug my problem myself, especially while trying to formulate a coherent and detailed enough question body in order to get decent answers.

Is this common?

Comment: Since this question is linked to a post from Jeff Atwood, I guess you'll get soon a gold badge :-)

Comment: @LucM Thats true! Before reading Jeff Atwood's post, I didn't know there is a meta stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes!
This technique is known as [Rubber Duck Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) -

> The process is to meticulously explain code to an inanimate object, such as a rubber duck. It is expected that when the programmer comes across a piece of code that is incorrect, she will realize this.

Comment: Thanks for putting a name to it! Although I prefer doing this on stackoverflow, because if I haven't found the problem by the end of my post, I can just hit "Post your question" and expect / receive answers. And talking to a rubber duck seems ... whacky :)

Comment: It's from a book titled "The Pragmatic Programmer" @ http://www.amazon.com/Pragmatic-Programmer-Journeyman-Master/dp/020161622X

Comment: Where I work we call it the FIP effect. "FIP" is a stuffed boarder collie who is named after a poorly named variable. You could use this to your advantage by still asking the question and then posting and accepting your own answer.

Comment: 'She' meaning the duck, of course...

Answer (score 9):

Often times this will happen when I'm preparing to ask a question on SO. My question will be far too specific to my code, so I'll be working out how to generalize it. More often than not, the process of generalizing a problem makes me aware of a mistake or design flaw in my "real" code, and hence solves my problem.